How to Choose the Best mRNA Data for miRNA Target Prediction Using psRNATarget: Exons from Assembly vs. Transcriptome Data?
I want to study the target prediction of miRNAs using psRNATarget tool. I have already completed the de novo assembly of this plant genome, and predicted the coding sequences. Now, to perform this target prediction, I need mRNA data. I am confused as to what can make better mRNA data, here. I have three options:

Extract exons from the assembly file, transcribe them to RNA and use the data
Transcriptome data is available for the same species but different tissue (inflorescence as opposed to shoot meristem in my case). Use this transcriptome data.
Merge the above transcriptome data with the transcriptome data of a closely related genera (meristem tissue), and use this data.

I am a bit confused. Can someone help me with a rational decision, here?

There have been multiple requests to close the question. Firstly, don't attempt exon assembly as a substitute of mRNA data (option 1). Option 3 looks the best course of action to me. The rationale for this is more complicated.
